# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spectrogram'

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, audio, scipy

Currently, I'm writing a python script, which should do the following:

- read an audio file respectively a wav file via scipy.io.wavfile.read().
- calculate the spectrogram of given wav file.
- write the data from spectrogram back into a wav file.

When I try to run the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo2.py", line 61, in <module>
    F,T,S = scipy.signal.spectrogram(s_mono,rate,window,None,nOverlap,nFFT)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spectrogram'
```

Which is rather strange, because in my opinion my code should work fine. I've already checked for Syntax Errors and I also looked up in the official scipy documentation but I couldn't find any clue what could possible be wrong with it.

Here's a little snippet of my code:

```
import scipy
from scipy import signal
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
#---------------------------------

# here's the rest of my code    

F,T,S = scipy.signal.spectrogram(s_mono,rate,window,None,nOverlap,nFFT)
```

Additional Information: I'm working on a MacBook with MacOS 10.9.5

Comment: So my answer worked for you?

Comment: Basically yes. I reinstalled everything I had. And it seemed that I had two versions of scipy on my computer, which caused also trouble. Now everything just works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no signal.py, uninstall scipy and reinstall it without using pip. Get it from their website. Getting it with pip seems to almost always have problems.

Comment: The funny part is, that I tried it with F,T,S = signal.spectrogram(s_mono,rate,window,None,nOverlap,nFFT) but I get the same error.

Comment: which python version are you using? how it's named your own python script file?

Comment: Ok. Now try removing the "from scipy import signal" but keeping "F,T,S = scipy.signal.spectrogram(s_mono,rate,window,None,nOverlap,nFFT)" as it originally was.

Comment: @BangTheBank: I'm using Python 2.7.5.

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape: I also tried this one before, but it didn't work :/

Comment: @Nico how your script is named? if your script file is named signal.py you could have weird errors.

Comment: @BangTheBank: My script name is "demo2.py"

Comment: Go to where the scipy is stored and make sure there is a signal file and look for spectrogram

Comment: @BangTheBank: So I checked out, if there is a signal.py file in my scipy directory and there is non, only spectral.py, which contains spectrogram.

Comment: Alright. Try `from scipy import spectral` and `F,T,S = spectral.spectrogram(s_mono,rate,window,None,nOverlap,nFFT)` . Did you get your scipy from a different place?

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape I got my scipy from the official website and installed it via pip. And I tried your method and now I get an Import Error

Comment: I'm going to change my answer and I feel like it's the only reasonable thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if this works for you:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(10000)
sig = np.sin(2. * math.pi * 1 / 1000. * t)
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(sig, 1.)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

It works for me with python 2.7 and scipy 0.19.

If this works for you, then you are probably causing some weird namespace errors in your script (calling a variable `signal`, etc.).

Comment: The moment I try to call signal.spectrogram, I get an attribute error.

Comment: Have you tried the following:
`from scipy.signal import spectral as spcl;

sss = spcl.spectrogram(x, fs)
`
It works for periodogram, welch and lombscargle but not for csd, coherence & spectrogram. Spectrogram function resides in spectral.py. 

Any expert advise?

Comment: Thanks - that test worked correctly.  Python 3.9 Mac BigSur.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with this ... caused by my bad variable assignments.

This is how I read and process a wav file. Please note the wave file needs to have metadata stripped (I used ffmpeg to do this)

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import soundfile as sf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
datasignal, fs_rate= sf.read('40m_stripped.wav')
print(f"Data shape is {datasignal.shape}")
sig=datasignal[::,0]
print(f"Sig shape is {sig.shape}")
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(sig, fs_rate)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```